# unknown error: Unsupported locator strategy: -android uiautomator

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am automating mobile web application using Appium Server and Selenium.
All I want to do is to retrieve the titles of android notification, to achieve this i tried to using the locator: findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator  to identify an element using resourceId.

Below is the code written by me:

```
package com.roofandfloor.test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class test02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        DesiredCapabilities desc = null;
         URL url = null;
        desc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desc.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
        desc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        desc.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
        desc.setCapability("deviceName", "Lenovo K50a40");
        desc.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        desc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
        desc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
        url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(url,desc);
        driver.openNotifications();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        List<WebElement>allNotifications=driver.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"android:id/title\")");
        System.out.println(allNotifications.size());
    }
}
```

When I run the above code I am getting the error shown below:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Unsupported locator strategy: -android uiautomator
```

I have alternatively tried to  use the below code.

```
List<WebElement>allNotifications=driver.findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"android:id/title\")"));
```

I am getting the same error as above.

Please help me resolving the issue.